# Xcode's Refactor menu is always disabled

Tags: iphone, xcode

For some reason Xcode's Refactor is always disabled. I used to be able to activate it via selecting a class name and right clicking in the editor to select it.  But now no matter what I do, it remains disabled.  Any idea what's going on?

Comment: I have the same problem. I looked at the activity window...nothing is going on. I'm running XCode 3.1.4. The solution below doesn't solve my issue. I've even checked the link mentioned by tewha, and I'm exhausting all possibilities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your project's index might be out of date/corrupt. In the General tab of the Project Settings window, click Rebuild Code Index and wait until it's done.

You can check the progress of the rebuild in the Activity window (Window > Activity).

Comment: I just encountered this in XCode 4 and here is what worked for me, since "Rebuild Code Index" is no longer where mentioned.

1) Open organizer
2) Select Projects tab
3) Click "Delete" next to "Derived Data"

Answer (score 13):

Working with Xcode 5, I kept getting "Can't refactor during indexing" when trying to refactor. Rebuilding the index seemed to hang at "Indexing - Waiting for make" forever.

I then noticed that make was already used by another process on my machine (not by Xcode). Shutting this process down enabled Xcode to finally finish indexing

Comment: Holy smoke. We use make for other local processes to mimic server processes, this was the smoking gun. Thank you @Katlu.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into a similar problem in Xcode.  I could not refactor anything in the class's .m (implementation file).  The only explanation I could come up with is that it was not indexing the file for some reason, and I could not force it to reindex.  The only hack that I found that worked was to copy the file to temporary location, remove it from my Xcode project, copy the file from the temp location back to my project's location, and then re-add the file via Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

None of these suggestions work for Xcode 3.2 - the ONLY way is to select the file you want to rename in the left Groups & Files column. THEN highlight the name of the .m or .h in the right code view, then you can right click and select Refactor!

For instance if you're changing the DetailViewController name, highlight the actual DetailViewController.h word in code.

Note, you should also always make sure you've selected the .h file, not the .m

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same thing in Xcode 11. and this worked for me:
[image]

I changed iPhone 8 simulator to generic iOS Device and it worked when it is on Generic

Answer (score -1):

I'm new in iOS development,I have met this similar problem.

Xcode:Version 7.1 (7B91b),it looks like Refactor not working:

[image]

***But when I put my mouse on the red circle point in the following picture，and then the Refactor working.***

[image]

***I think this is a low level mistake,but may be a reference for someone.***